# How to integrate facebook, twitter and google plus to an android app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, integration, social-networking

I like to integrate Facebook, twitter and Google plus to my app, so that using the app, user can update their status. Therefore I like to know how this can be done.

Thanks

Comment: This could have been answered with a few Google and SO searches... you probably should at least show some effort next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As for facebook and twitter, you can do this through their API. For facebook, fortunately they have provide android developer with [facebook sdk for android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android), example included on the SDK.

And for Twitter you can use external libraries as written on [twitter developer docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#java), and there is a library called [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) that is android ready.

Unfortunately Google Plus API are not available yet.

Answer (score 14):

I would highly recommend not to use those SDK since they contain a lot of bugs, and are not very reliable as far as I've seen.

If you just want to share simple text from your app to Facebook or Twitter and so on... I would recommend to create a chooser to let the user pick which app from his phone he wants to user for sharing. It is simpler, more reliable and more the 'android way' of doing it.

Here is the code that you have to write :

```
Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"I want to share this with you!");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Great Post");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

Answer (score 3):

Now you can try this library: https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

It's very easy to use:

```
mSocialNetworkManager = (SocialNetworkManager) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG);

if (mSocialNetworkManager == null) {
    mSocialNetworkManager = SocialNetworkManager.Builder.from(getActivity())
            .twitter(<< TWITTER  API TOKEN  >>, << TWITTER  API SECRET  >>)
            .linkedIn(<< LINKED_IN  API TOKEN  >>, << LINKED_IN API TOKEN  >>, "r_basicprofile+rw_nus+r_network+w_messages")
            .facebook()
            .googlePlus()
            .build();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mSocialNetworkManager, SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG).commit();
}
```

...

```
mSocialNetworkManager.getTwitterSocialNetwork().requestLogin(new OnLoginCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(int socialNetworkID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int socialNetworkID, String requestID, String errorMessage, Object data) {

    }
});
```

Comment: How to get the user's e-mail?

Comment: Some necessary features for Google Plus missed for now. Like post and list of friends. Hope you will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your app you can use Fabric IDE plugins to integrate your app with twitter.
With Fabric you can integrate twitter in simple steps
The Fabric IDE plugins will automatically create and configure a Twitter application when you use it to integrate the Twitter Kit into your app.
You can read related documentation on below link-
https://docs.fabric.io/android/index.html