# Set color of ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-styles, shareactionprovider

I defined a color for my whole app (a dark grey) and so when I click on the ShareActionProvider, a black list shows up but the text color is dark grey too (and so not really visible). The text in the ActionBar is white, but not the one in the list.

Is there any way I can set a different color (some item in styles.xml ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way to customize shareActionProvider is create separate menu specifically for Sharing. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192759/1237175

Comment: I want to use the native ShareActionProvider, I'd just like to change the text color (actually to set it back to its normal value = white)

Comment: you can change the style